# Start firefox full screen when Mac mini starts + run another app minimized

Tags: macos, startup, fullscreen

Does someone know how I can fix the following:

1) When my mac mini starts, open Firefox in fullscreen mode (I'm using R-kiosk now) and give focus to this new instance of Firefox. The problem I have now, is that Firefox is started in fullscreen mode, but another app (see 2) is put on top of this window.

2) And.. how can I start an application minimized? (I added the application to startup-items in systempreferences > Users > [user] > Startup items and checked the hide box).

Thanks!
Roxlu

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out!

1. Create a Automator app
2. Add a "Launch application"
3. Add a "Applescript"

With something like this:

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 101
```